# PM2 does not restart my process after an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2, discord.js

I googled a lot and read through Stackoverflow, but found no solution to my problem.
I have 4 processes running on PM2 (*LenoxBot, Proposalbot, Bugbot and a webhook*).

Tonight all my 4 processes crashed because of one error that isn't the cause of this problem.

I now ask myself 2 questions:

1. **Why are all my 4 processes crashing when one has an error?**
2. **Why do not my processes restart?**

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Show your PM2 config too please.

Comment: You mean the process file? @FaizuddinMohammed

Comment: Yes. Are you simply starting with something like `pm2 server.js`?

Comment: Yes I simply do `pm2 start lenoxbotapp` @FaizuddinMohammed

Comment: In that case, it's hard to find out what's happening. I have no idea. :(

Comment: I think it does not change much if I start the server now with a process file or the normal command, right? @FaizuddinMohammed

Comment: It doesn't. Yeah. I was expecting something to be wrong in the process file.

Comment: if you do not care about the crash and debugging you can run the 4 processes under forever

Comment: Normally pm2 should also run the processes forever @split